# Universal converter to PDF

Tags: python, file, pdf, converters, file-conversion

I have a thousand of documents.
The formats of them are as following:

**"xls, xlsx, csv, ppt, pptx, doc, docx, txt"**

Is there any library that can do this job? I have found one called PDFTron, but seems it needs license.
Here is my sample code that will copy files first and then convert non-PDFs

```
import os
import shutil

src = ".../srcpaths"
dst = ".../dstpaths"
ext = ['xls', 'xlsx', 'csv', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'doc', 'docx', 'txt', 'pdf']

for root, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(src):               # for all folders and files
    for filename in filenames:                                 # for all names
        if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in ext:
            shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(dst, filename))  # cope files with its path(root)
        
        
def ConvertToPDF(ext):
    ########converter code#####

ConvertToPDF('.xls')
ConvertToPDF('.xlsx')
ConvertToPDF('.csv')
ConvertToPDF('.ppt')
ConvertToPDF('.pptx')
ConvertToPDF('.doc')
ConvertToPDF('.docx')
ConvertToPDF('.txt')
```

Comment: apparently, the issue is not about having the license, which is free, but about preserving confidentiality of the files

Comment: Nope, it's okay for the regular end user. It's just some companies that doesn't allow to process their data using third party web apps. Btw, I just have found unoconv, will try this one out 
github.com/unoconv/unoconv

Comment: oh, that makes sense now. I'll check this out. Thanks @KJ !

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no universal `ConvertToPDF` library.  But you might get reasonable results with `pandoc`.  I very much doubt you'll find a python library to do it, however.