# Universal PDF converter

Tags: python, pdf, libreoffice, converters, doc

I am looking for a help with "any document converter", where any document file [doc, docx, ppt, pptx] will be converted to pdf. DOCX and PPTX are easy to handle with python libraries, but DOC and PPT is a bit tricky.
The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69303392/universal-converter-to-pdf) I've got 7 month ago was quite a bit hard to deal with. Especially the one with use of Unoconv (now its deprecated and changed to Unoserv).

Initial code example:

```
import os
import shutil

src = ".../srcpaths"
dst = ".../dstpaths"
ext = ['ppt', 'pptx', 'doc', 'docx']

for root, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(src):
    for filename in filenames:
        if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in ext:
            shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(dst, filename))            
        
def ConvertToPDF(ext):
    #some code#

ConvertToPDF('.ppt')
ConvertToPDF('.pptx')
ConvertToPDF('.doc')
ConvertToPDF('.docx')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my review of solutions and an answer at the end:

**1. Pandoc:**

- requires pdf latex processor
- not preserving the shape of files well
- loss of formatting
- problems with graphics
- problems with charts
- problems with fonts
- low on formats choice

**2. Unoconv/Unoserver**

- hard to install and deal with
- requires Libre Office as engine
- good conversion results (not perfect)

**3. Cloud-based solutions:**

- not free
- not open-source friendly
- privacy concerns

**4. Google Drive API converter:**

- using someone’s account
- upload document – Convert it – Save it as PDF
- privacy concerns

**5. LibreLambda**

- uses Amazon Web Services (AWS)
- privacy concerns

**Simple solution:**

Use the software straightly by running it in a cmd subprocess.

Needs: installation of LibreOffice.
Biggest advantage: can run both on Windows and Linux (should be modified for linux)

Here is my Python code for Windows:

```
import os
import subprocess

# path to the engine
path_to_office = r"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe"

# path with files to convert
source_folder = r"C:\ConvertToPDF\input_files"

# path with pdf files
output_folder = r"C:\ConvertToPDF\output_files"

# changing directory to source
os.chdir(source_folder)

# assign and running the command of converting files through LibreOffice
command = f"\"{path_to_office}\" --convert-to pdf  --outdir \"{output_folder}\" *.*"
subprocess.run(command)

print('Converted')
```

If you can modify it to Linux, please feel free to share your solution

Comment: Linux solution:

command = r"lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf input_files/*.*  --outdir output_files"
subprocess.run(command, shell=True)